# Glitch like image on firefox when using background: url

Tags: html, css

Can any one explain why this happens on firefox and how to prevent it. The css for the div containing the image is shown below

```
height: 803px;
background: url("/img/somejpg.jpg") center center no-repeat;
background-size: cover !important;
```

Firefox briefly shows this glitch image and I will like to find a way to stop it
[image: Glitch Image]

Comment: What version of firefox are you using, and what operating system? Also, is the image always the same?

Comment: Can you please provide a jsfiddle or similar example that reproduces this issue for you?